# Ansible Compare INI Local against Remote

Tags: ansible

I have a Java Properities file on my Ansible Server and remote machine

Server: /opt/deployment/application/build.properities

```
app=application
build=1.0.15
etc=etc
```

On the remote machine is the same file (if it's installed) which could contain a newer or older version

Remote: /opt/application/build.properities

```
app=application
build=1.0.13
config1=config
etc=etc
```

Can I use ansible.builtin.ini to compare the build number on my remote machine to the server and:

`if server > remote - do my upgrade block`

`if remote == "" (file does not exist) - do my install block`

`otherwise do nothing`

It wasn't clear to me if ansible.builtin.ini was targeting the local server or the remote machine (I probably missed something).  Both machines are Ubuntu Linux if that makes a difference.

Comment: You can use `slurp` to read in the contents of a remote file into a variable, and then use that for comparison. `ansible.builtin.ini` is an inventory plugin - you probably mean `community.general.ini_file`?

Comment: Why don't you just use the `copy` module? It will create the file if needed, update it if different and do nothing if they are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working in the end and wanted to share the code I used...

```
- name: Check if App is installed
  stat:
    path: "{{ app_buildfile }}"
  register: APPbuildfile

- name: Get Build Number
  shell: grep build {{ APP_buildfile }}  | awk -F'=' ' { print $2 } ' | tr -d ' '
  when: APPbuildfile.stat.exists
  register: APP_currentbuild

- debug:
    msg: Current version {{ APP_currentbuild.stdout }}, Deployment Version {{ APP_deployment_version }}

- name: New Installation
  block:
    - Install Actions....
    - name: Set actioned fact
      set_fact:
        actioned: 1

  when: APP_currentbuild is not defined


- name: Upgrade Installation
  block:
    - Upgrade Actions...

    - name: Set actioned fact
      set_fact:
        actioned: 2
  when: APP_currentbuild.stdout|length == 0 or APP_currentbuild.stdout is version(APP_deployment_version,'lt')
  
- name: Post Install Tasks
  block:
    - Post install actions...

  when: actioned is defined
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to give the big picture after my comment. Copy the file and notify a handler if it changed. Alternativelly you can register a variable on the task and check `when : <registered_var>.changed` but handlers are usually preferred.

```
---
- hosts: my_remote_group
  
  tasks:
    - name: Make sure remote ini file is aligned with controller
      copy:
        src: /opt/deployment/application/build.properties
        dest: /opt/application/build.properties
        owner: some_relevant_user
        group: some_relevant_group
        mode: 0660
      notify: upgrade_my_package

  handlers:
    - name: Upgrade my package
      listen: upgrade_my_package
      debug:
        msg: "Do whatever is needed to upgrade my package if ini files are different. Use an include_task module if needed"
```

Comment: The file can be customised locally, the copy module would overwrite it, it need to check the value inside of it sadly, but otherwise this would be good